# SQL - Altering the position of field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to alter the position of a field using a query, not designer. Example - my table1 has fieldnames as follows

```
field1
field2
field4
field3
```

`field3` should be in position of `field4`.

Comment: You can't easily do this, unless you create a new table.

Comment: Create a new table, copy the data, delete the original table, rename the new table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in such way that `Add a new col` to the `table`. Then `copy` the `values of FIELD4` into it. then `drop the col FIELD4` and `named new col as FIELD4`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do it in quite some steps:

1. Add a new field:

   ```
   alter table  mytable add field5 mydatatype
   ```
2. Copy the values of existing field to the new one:

   ```
    INSERT INTO mytable
           (field5))
           SELECT field4
           FROM mytable;
   ```
3. Drop old field:

   ```
   alter tble mytable drop column field4
   ```

4.rename the new field to one you dropped:

```
    sp_RENAME 'Mytable.field5' , 'field4', 'COLUMN'
```